# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.TextInput.propTypes.style') on mac OS, React native version 0.69.1

Tags: android, ios, react-native

After upgrading React Native version to `0.69.1`, I am getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.TextInput.propTypes.style') error every time when build app on iOS simulator which results blank screen on simulator and nothing is happening later.

I did some search on it and found that it is related to react-native-material-dropdown & react-native-material-textfield libraries but I am not using any of this lib in my project. Also did search in node-modules folder for error line but no results found.

Below is my package.json file,

```
  "name": "app name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "assets": [
    "./assets/fonts/"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.12",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.6",
    "@react-native/normalize-color": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.69.1",
    "react-native-calendar-strip": "^2.2.6",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.315.0",
    "react-native-camera-kit": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-expandable-listview": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.4",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
    "react-native-prevent-screenshot": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-generator": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-rating-element": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.15.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-tags-input": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-version-info": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.22.7",
    "rn-tri-toggle-switch": "^1.0.4",
    "rnschedule": "0.0.5",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.11.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "25.5.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

[image: error log on console]

Please let me know if anyone get such issue and how to get it fix that would be great.

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a fix?